# head | tail equivalent in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bash

I try to read the part of the txt-file with JS, but I cannot manage it clearly. 
In bash I could simply use:

```
head -50 file.txt | tail -10
```

to get lines 40-50 from my file. In JS I use jQuery.get() and it looks like this:

```
$.get( "file.txt", function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

to open the whole file. And it's ok, so I can split the data with this function:

```
function splitString(stringToSplit, separator) {
          var splits = stringToSplit.split('\n', 4);
          console.log(splits);
      }
```

But is there a way to split from the offset, so I could get lines 40-50 (for example).

Sorry for me poor explanation.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp This should help

Comment: @waldek_c thank you! Something tells me, that's not the best way to make an array from data, but anyway it works!